# How to get all the weekend dates of the current year in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I tried but could not get the right solution. I want an SQL query that lists all the weekend dates of the current year.

I tried this SQL query:

```
WITH hier(num, lvl) AS (
    SELECT  0, 1
            UNION ALL
    SELECT  100, 1
            UNION ALL 
    SELECT  num + 1, lvl + 1
    FROM    hier
    WHERE   lvl < 100 
)
SELECT lvl [Week], 
convert(date,DATEADD(dw, -DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,'12/31/'+convert(nvarchar,YEAR(getdate()))), 0)+6 ),
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,'12/31/'+convert(nvarchar,YEAR(getdate()))), 0)+6 ) - num  * 7,101) [End Date]
FROM    hier a
where   num < 52
ORDER BY [End Date] asc
```

Its output is like this:

```
Week  End date
52  2012-01-14
51  2012-01-21
50  2012-01-28
49  2012-02-04
```

I want the dates to start from the beginning – so, the above is missing one weekend, which is `2012-07-01`. Also, I want the week numbers to show as `1, 2, 3...` instead of `52, 51...`.

Comment: First, define what *you* mean by the week end date - different cultures define these things differently. Assuming you mean a weekend as Saturdays and Sundays, what date do you need? The saturday, the sunday, both? If both, as two columns in a single row, or as separate rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/29/sql-server-get-date-of-all-weekdays-or-weekends-of-the-year/) blog post.

Your question is explained in detail.

```
DECLARE @Year AS INT,
@FirstDateOfYear DATETIME,
@LastDateOfYear DATETIME
-- You can change @year to any year you desire
SELECT @year = 2010
SELECT @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
SELECT @LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0)
-- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 AS DayID,
@FirstDateOfYear AS FromDate,
DATENAME(dw, @FirstDateOfYear) AS Dayname
UNION ALL
SELECT cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
FROM cte
WHERE DATEADD(d,1,cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
)
SELECT FromDate AS Date, Dayname
FROM CTE
WHERE DayName IN ('Saturday','Sunday') -- For Weekend    
/*
WHERE DayName LIKE 'Sunday'
WHERE DayName NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday') -- For Weekday
WHERE DayName LIKE 'Monday' -- For Monday
WHERE DayName LIKE 'Sunday' -- For Sunday
*/
OPTION (MaxRecursion 370)
```

Comment: This solution relies on the user having English language settings (other cultures would have different date names)

Comment: @Kartik Patel WeekofYr = DATEPART(WEEK, FromDate).Even my query does the same

Answer (score 4):

Will this help

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
SELECT @startDate = '2012-01-01', @endDate = '2012-12-31'
;WITH Calender AS (
    SELECT @startDate AS dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dt + 1 FROM Calender
    WHERE dt + 1 <= @endDate
)
SELECT 
dt
,NameMonth = DATENAME(Month, dt)
,NameDay = DATENAME (Weekday,dt)
,WeekofYr = DATEPART(WEEK, dt)  FROM Calender
WHERE DATENAME (Weekday,dt) IN ('Sunday')
Option(MaxRecursion 0)
```

**Result(Partial)**

```
dt                      NameMonth   NameDay WeekofYr
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 January     Sunday  1
2012-01-08 00:00:00.000 January     Sunday  2
...............................................
...............................................
2012-12-30 00:00:00.000 December    Sunday  53
```

Comment: This solution *also* relies on the user having English language settings (other cultures would have different date names)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
DECLARE @FirstDateOfYear DATETIME
SET @FirstDateOfYear = ’2010-01-01′
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(d, number, @FirstDateOfYear),
CASE DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(d, number, @FirstDateOfYear))
WHEN 7 THEN ‘Saturday’
WHEN 1 THEN ‘Sunday’
ELSE ‘Work Day’
END
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND 364
AND (DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(d, number, @FirstDateOfYear)) = 1 OR DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(d, number, @FirstDateOfYear)) = 7)
ORDER BY DATEADD(d, number, @FirstDateOfYear)
```

Comment: can you please explain how it works? Its the most simple solution I have found. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the first Saturday by doing this:

1. Start on 2012-01-01
2. If it's not a Saturday, add a day
3. Goto 2

Then, into a temporary table, add that date and the following date (Sunday).
After that, loop the following:

1. Add 7 and 8 days to the last Saturday you found (you get the following Saturday and Sunday)
2. Check whether they are still in 2012
3. If they are, store them in temp table and goto 1

There may be more elegant ways, but that's my quick & dirty solution. As you didn't post any code of what you've tried, I'll leave the implementation up to you.

Answer (score 0):

this also works

```
declare @dat datetime, @add int

set @dat = '20120101'
set @add = datepart(w,@dat)

set @add = 5 - @add -- friday

set @dat = dateadd(d,@add,@dat)

while @dat <= '20121231'
begin
    print @dat
    set @dat = dateadd(d,7,@dat)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with AllDaysOfYear (Day) as (
    select DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0) --Jan 1st
    union all
    select DATEADD(day,1,Day) from AllDaysOfYear
    where DATEPART(year,DATEADD(day,1,Day)) = DATEPART(year,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
)
select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Day) as WeekNo,
    Day
from
    AllDaysOfYear
where
    DATEPART(weekday,Day) = DATEPART(weekday,'20120714')
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

First, generate a set of all of the days in the current year (`AllDaysInYear`). Then, select those whose `weekday` is a saturday. The value I've used (`'20120714'`) isn't terribly important - it just has to be *any* saturday, from any year. I'm just using it to avoid needing to have particular `DATEFIRST` or language settings.

Answer (score 0):

This query shows how to get the first day of this year and the first day of the next year in the first part.  The first day of the next year is calculated once so as not to keep getting and comparing the year parts.

```
;WITH cte(TheDate,NextYear) AS
(
  SELECT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(4),GETDATE(),112)+'0101' AS DATETIME),
         CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())*10000+10101 AS CHAR(8))
   UNION ALL
  SELECT DateAdd(d,1,TheDate),NextYear
    FROM cte
   WHERE DateAdd(d,1,TheDate)<NextYear
)
  SELECT Week = DatePart(wk,TheDate),
         TheDate
    FROM cte
   WHERE DateName(dw,TheDate) in ('Saturday')
ORDER BY TheDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as 
(
select 1 b
union all
select 1 b
union all
select 1 b
union all
select 1 b
union all
select 1 b
union all
select 1 b
union all
select 1 b
union all
select 1 b
) 
select * from 
(
select 
current_timestamp
-datepart(dy,current_timestamp)
+row_number() over (order by t.b) d
from t, t t1, t t2 
) tmp 
where datepart(yyyy,d)=datepart(yyyy,current_timestamp)
      and
      DATENAME(dw,d)='sunday'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Year AS INT

SELECT @Year = 2020

;WITH weekends AS (
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 1, 1) AS dt
          UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, dt) 
      FROM weekends
     WHERE dt < DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, 12, 31)
)
SELECT dt, DATENAME(MONTH, dt), DATENAME(DW, dt)
FROM weekends
WHERE DATEPART(DW, dt) IN (1, 7)
OPTION(MaxRecursion 366)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.